# bytes('\xFF', 'utf-8') returns

Tags: python, struct, byte

I'm currently working on a BlueTooth LE project, the bluepy module requires me to send data as bytes ...
I would like to send b'\xFF' so I write:

```
bytes('\xff', 'utf-8')
```

that returns:

```
b'\xc3\xbf'
```

Investigating a little further I found that actually happens for all uint-8 numbers above 127.

Digging in search of a solution, I found numerous Q&A's that suggest using struct.unpack, sorry no luck there ...

```
>>> type(struct.unpack('B', b'\xff')[0])
<class 'int'>
```

struct.unpack returns a number of class int. 
By now i found that:

```
b'\xFF'
```

actually produces the byte with all ones ... I however would still like to have this behavior of both bytes() and struct.unpack() explained to me. (Python 3.5.3 on Raspberry Pi 3)

Thanks a lot,

KK

Comment: If you need to send the exact raw bytes, then I think all you need is '\xff'. If you do `bytes('\xff', 'utf-8') you get the utf-8 encoding of `\xff', which is what you saw - I'm not familiar with bluepy, but I would guess that what it expects is the raw bytes, and not some type of encoded string.

Comment: If I send the the raw byte i.e. '\xff' that gets interpreted as a string and gives me the corresponding error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" from bluepy. Like I said b'\xFF' does the trick but leaves me with a lot of packing if i want to use variables in stead of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found the solution to my problem myself ...

```
n = 255
bytes([n])
```

will do the trick. Kind a puzzled about the logic of the square brackets, but we're in the solution business, let 's leave theory to the real experts. :-)

Comment: The square brackets are because a `bytes` is actually an array of small integers and to build the array you need to supply it a list of values. Your original problem was that calling `bytes('\xff')` is passing it a *Unicode string of length 1*, not a byte string of length 1. It should have been `bytes(b'\xff')`. To see this type `bytes([255]) == bytes(b'\xff')` at the Python prompt.